# AlarmManager PendingIntent not received by the service

Tags: android

The AlarmManager sends the intent after a minute in the activities **onDestroy** method.

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MyService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

The intent send by the alarmManager is expected to invoke the MyService::onStartCommand method
 which will log the message "OnReceive". But this does not happen.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    static public MediaPlayer mp;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MyService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

with this,

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MyService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

If you have any query, Please let me know.